# printing 1 instead of filenames

Tags: php, readdir

I have some image collection in my specied directory.And i want to get their name using readdir() function.But instead of showing their names,it prints out a series of 1.How this can be done correctly ??I also want to know the reason for this behaviour

```
$dir='c:/xampp/htdocs/practice/haha/';
echo getcwd().'</br>';
if(is_dir($dir)){
echo dirname($dir);
     $file=opendir($dir);

     while($data=readdir($file)!==false){
        echo $data.'</br>';
     }

}
```

[image]

Comment: `$data=readdir($file)!==false` should be `($data=readdir($file))!==false`

Comment: My guess is that this might be an order of operations problem...`$data` is being assigned the value of `readdir($file)!==false`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operator precedence. This line:

```
 while($data=readdir($file)!==false){
```

is being parsed/executed as

```
 while ($data = (readdir($file) !== false))
                ^------------------------^
```

Note the extra brackets. `$data` is getting the boolean TRUE result of the `!==` comparison. You need to rewerite as

```
 while(($data = readdir($file)) !== false){
       ^----------------------^
```

That'll make `$data` get the string returned from `readdir`, and then that string will be compared with boolean `false`.

Relevant docs: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: it didn't cross my mind at first.Nice explanation :))

Answer (score 1):

You probably can implement instead with `scandir`

```
function list_directory($directory) {
  $result = new stdClass();
  $result->path = $directory;
  $result->children = array();
  $dir = scandir($directory);
  foreach($dir as $file) {
    if($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;
    $result->children[] = 
        !is_dir($directory.$file) ? $file :
            list_directory($directory.$file.'/');
  }
  return $result;
}

$dir='c:/xampp/htdocs/practice/haha/';

$result = list_directory($dir);
echo '<code><pre>';
var_dump($result);
echo '</pre></code>';
```

You can add in the function a filter for filetypes, or limit depth of recursion, things like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data=readdir($file)!==false
```

You're setting the boolean result to `$data`. Surely you meant to do:

```
($data=readdir($file))!==false
```